# Why do I keep getting this message when I try to download a go package?

Tags: go, caching, go-get, go-fiber

```
C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\code\projects\weatherly>go get -u github.com/gofiber/fiber/v2 
cannot find package "github.com/gofiber/fiber/v2" in any of:
        c:\go\src\github.com\gofiber\fiber\v2 (from $GOROOT)
        C:\Users\Administrator\go\src\github.com\gofiber\fiber\v2 (from $GOPATH)
```

How do I download the package? I believe that it is trying to check what is cached on my computer and I don't know how to download it first.

Comment: *"I don't know how to download it first"* -- Try without `-u` and `-f`.

Comment: It is because of `/v2` tail. You should follow instructions and first run `go mod init` to properly initialize your project for use with modules. See https://github.com/gofiber/fiber#%EF%B8%8F-installation

Answer (score 1):

Its because you haven't initiated your module, you should use `go mod init YourModuleName`, then its pretty simple to do. also remove -f from go get command.